# How to wrap every string with an html tag in an html string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need to convert this:

```
<b>LOREM IPSUM<br/></b>DOLOR SIT AMET
```

to this:

```
<b><span>LOREM</span> <span>IPSUM</span><br/></b><span>DOLOR</span> <span>SIT</span> <span>AMET</span>
```

How can i do it?

I tried this:

```
string.replace(/(^|<\/?[^>]+>|\s+)([^\s<]+)/g, `<span>$&</span>`)
```

But it removes `</b>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex, try a simple state machine

```
function addSpanTags(input)
{
  let output = "";
  let inTag = false;
  let inWord = false;
  for (let i = 0;  i<input.length; i++) {
    let c = input[i];
    if (inTag) {
      if (c == '>') {
        inTag = false;
      }
      output += c;
    }
    else if (inWord) {
      if (c.trim() === '') { // whitespace
        inWord = false
        output += "</span>"
      }
      else if (c == '<') {
        inTag = true
        inWord = false
        output += "</span>"
      }
      output += c
    }
    else {
      if (c == '<') {
        inTag = true
        output += c
      }
      else if (c.trim() === '') { // whitespace
        output += c + "<span>"
      }
      else {
        inWord = true
        output += "<span>" + c
      }
    }
  }
  if (inWord) {
    output += "</span>"
  }
  return output
}
```

Usage:

```
let input = "<b>LOREM IPSUM<br/></b>DOLOR SIT AMET";
let output = addSpanTags(input)
console.log(output)
```